# Usage of the two "over"

Tags: prepositions

> Borrower SES Global Americas Holdings GP
>
> Issue Amount 500 million euro
>
> Maturity Date October 24, 2018
>
> Coupon 1.875 pct
>
> Reoffer price 99.172
>
> Yield 2.051 pct
>
> Spread 73 basis points
>
> Underlying govt bond **Over** Mid-swaps, equivalent to 116.7bp
>
> **Over** the OBL 167
>
> Payment Date October 24, 2013
>
> Lead Manager(s) BNP Paribas, CA - CIB, Commerzbank, Mizuho, MUSI &
> BCEE
>
> -- [New Issue-SES Global Americas prices 500 mln euro 2018 bond](http://www.reuters.com/article/2013/10/16/idUSL3N0I630220131016)

I don't quite understand the two "over" here. They seem to mean "more than" or "in exchange for", but I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've figured it out. "Over" here means "more than".

That part can be interpreted as:

"Yield 2.051% = 73 basis points + 5-year euro swap rate (set on the SES bond issuance date) = 116.7 basis points + yield on German federal government 5-year notes Series 167 (set on the SES bond issuance date)."

Sorry for the jargon in the question and answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here, it means **more than** or **beyond**.

*Over* can also mean

> Meaning -- Usage example:
>
> 1. beyond -- Over there
> 2. above / on top of -- over the mountains
> 3. finished -- The function was over when I reached
> 4. about/surrounding -- Jackie, the dog was all over me with joy
> 5. more than -- over 1000 years ago
>
> Also, 6 balls make an "Over" in Cricket.